# Setting property values in ILOG Rules for .NET

Tags: ilog

When a business rule tries to set a  property value of an element of a collection (an array), an `InvalidCastException` is raised when setting the ruleset of the engine.

This does not happen if we set the property value of an object. Neither it happens if we set 
attribute of the elements of the collection using a method.

This happens both if the application logic and class libraries are in C# or in VB.NET.